# Ignoring a model with all blank fields in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to create multiple items (each with a name value and a content value) in a single form.  The code I have is functioning, but I cannot figure out how to ignore items that are blank.  Here's the code:

```
#item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :content
 validates_presence_of :name, :content 
end

#items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController  

def new
  @items = Array.new(3){ Item.new } 
end

def create
 @items = params[:items].values.collect{|item|Item.new(item)}
 if @items.each(&:save!)
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created item."
  redirect_to root_url
 else
  render :action => 'new'
 end
end

#new.html.erb
<% form_tag :action => 'create' do %>
 <%@items.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
  <% fields_for "items[#{index}]", item do |f| %>
  <p>
   Name: <%= f.text_field :name  %>
   Content: <%= f.text_field :content  %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
 <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

This code works when all fields for all items are filled out in the form, but fails if any fields are left blank (due to validations).  The goal is that 1 or 2 items could be saved, even if others are left blank.

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, but I've been tinkering for hours with no avail.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you should filter params at controller level.

Comment: @apneadiving - could you be more specific? i'm not sure how exactly that would work. thanks!

Comment: You should follow cam's way of coding but you should work with the params hash. I agree to have a look but please provide me with a params sample (look at your log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
class Item
  def empty?
    attributes.values.compact.empty?
  end
end

# in ItemsController
if @items.reject(&:empty?).all(&:save)
```

A couple notes:

1. You were using `save!`, but you probably want `save`. `save!` would raise an exception if one of the items was invalid, and you'd just see an error page instead of your `new` template.
2. I replaced `each` with `all`. `each` wouldn't do what you intended--which is to return `true` if and only if all of the Items validated and saved. `all` does just that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This seems like it would work, but I just realized I forgot to include an important piece of code.  Every item is pre-populated with a project id in the form(<%= f.hidden_field :project_id %>.  As a result, the none of the items would be considered empty.  What's the workaround for this? How do I ignore the project id value when checking for empty?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment.  I figured it out.  Instead of 'attributes.values.compact.empty?' in the empty? method I wrote 'name.empty? && 'content.empty?'.  That worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but perhaps you could do something like:

```
@items.reject! { |item| item.attributes.values.compact.empty? }
```

Comment: What if every item is pre-populated with a value (from a hidden field in the form)?  Since none of the items are empty, they all pass... which presents a problem.  How do we ignore certain values when checking for empty?

Comment: In that case maybe the best bet would be to add a `default?` method to your model (it would check the the attributes of the model against whatever pre-populated values you have).  Then change your reject line to `@items.reject! { |item| item.default? }`